# Aggregate results from multiple mySQL databases in PHP

Tags: php, sql, parallel-processing, aggregate, olap

I have a large # (say 100) of databases with identical schemas and want to do SQL aggregates across this entire collection of databases.

Lets say the table is ATHLETES

```
CREATE TABLE ATHLETES(JERSEYNUM, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, TEAMNAME, SPORT)
```

I want to be able to dynamically specify a query like

```
SELECT SPORT, COUNT(*) FROM ATHLETES GROUP BY SPORT
```

And have it run across all 100 of my databases, producing one combined result set.

The important thing is I want to do this dynamically -- I want to type a SQL query into a PHP-based web UI  and execute it.

Also these queries are typically slow (3 min each),  so I'd rather they run in parallel then in serial and take 300 mins.

Comment: Why 100+ databases with the same table? Why does a single database query take 3 minutes? What is(are) the platform(s)? And what do you mean by "database" - in other words just one instance/engine/installation containing all "databases" within that one instance or across 100+ different instances?

Comment: The databases are very large,  each on their own machine.    They are split into separate machines to help with load & data size.  The tables are so big that the queries can take some time.

Comment: Any answer would have to be platform-dependent. Based on the limited information, this physical and logical setup is deeply flawed. What is very large to you?

Comment: It's about one billion rows per db

Comment: So what are you going to do with your set of data that requires full table scams of billions of rows derived from 100 or so servers? That would also drive the solution. How up to date does this data need to be? Does the data need to be serially consistent across all 100 "nodes"?

Comment: It is count(*) group byt has to be up to date.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should create a table with the databases login data and then loop through all the db's with your query and collect the data in php arrays. As far as I know is possible to join tables but not join db's? I don't think it will be possible to run parallel queries.